# Cancel FB.api(...) Request

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm calling FB.api(...) with an FQL query whenever an *input*'s **keyup** event is fired. Is it possible to cancel the previous request to query the (newer) updated query, or do I have to wait it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the request is already sent, then it could not be canceled.

What you could do is to delay sending the request by using `setTimeout`, and cancel the previous delay when the next keyup event fired.